# How do I turn on code completion in Dev-C++?

Tags: c++, ide

I am using Dev-C++ version 5.11. It has feature of code completion, but it is not turned on. I don't know how to do that because I am using Dev-C++ for the first time. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: If you are looking for a minimalistic C++ IDE, take a look at [Jucipp](https://github.com/cppit/jucipp) its a minimalistic modern cross compatible IDE.

Comment: Also can give https://www.geany.org/ a try. Its easy and lightweight

Answer (score 3):

You need to go to Tools->Editor Options->Completion->The tab code completion and then click "Enable code completion" box
you can also change the delay with which the prediction will be made

**Note**: Its not going to predict variables names or function names. By the time i write this, it only predict things you put after the -> operator

Answer (score 0):

It's not gonna show you the member functions inside your header file if you're calling the class member functions from another file. works if you use the class and main in the same file.

Answer (score -4):

**My man I have the answer**

--DevC++ is an awesome IDE and I don't have any plans to move to any other IDE. So I found Intellisense in DevC++ and the best part YOU DON'T NEED ANY ADDONS OR PLUGINS it's just hidden in the DevC++ shortcuts. (**I have been using Dev C++ NEWER VERSION so I dont know about the old version and I do recommend the new version found on sourceforge**) so when you need Intellisense simply press Ctrl+Space. Yup That's it . Just try  .U Can thank me later...................