# Problem suggesting and completing code in dev c ++

Tags: c++, dev-c++

I recently installed dev c ++ 6.3, but it does not suggest and complete the code. How can I enable this feature?

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39545027/how-do-i-turn-on-code-completion-in-dev-c

Comment: Devc++ is not supporting anymore. Please use another tool.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I turn on code completion in Dev-C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39545027/how-do-i-turn-on-code-completion-in-dev-c)

Answer (score 0):

go to `Tools->Editor Options->Completion->The tab code completion->Enable code completion`

However, you shouldn't be using it.use the latest `code:blocks` or `vscode`

Comment: Thank you, this part was seen, but it seems that the expectation that vs code was created is not fulfilled here.